# Microsoft WORD in footer How to get it to say the next page number, or that it is the last page

Tags: microsoft-word, footers

continue on and last page

`{If {PAGE} < {NUMPAGES} "Continue on {={PAGE}+1}" "last page" }`

I can't seem to get this to work, it keeps printing "last page" or the text '{If {PAGE} < {NUMPAGES} "Continue on {={PAGE}+1}" "last page" }' shows up.

some times <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> removes the  `{={PAGE}+1}`

Mostly it just shows "last page" on all the pages.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. If I understand what you are asking for, the problem is that you used `NUMPAGE`, and it needs to be `NUMPAGES`. If that helps, we can work together to improve the question so it can be re-opened and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to enter the brackets "{ }" in which you insert the conditional formatting.  This applies to nested conditional formatting as well as the top-level statement.  There should be a space after every open bracket and a space before the close bracket, as shown here: {   FIELDNAME   }.

Couple of other comments:  You're not displaying the page number of the page that you're on, but you're referring to the next page number.  Also, what is the desired result if the condition isn't met?  Do you want the page number displayed?  From what I see, you'll only get "last page" but no page number if the page number equals NUMPAGES (last page in section).  Try this:

{ IF{ PAGE } < { NUMPAGES } "Page { PAGE } (continued on page { ={ PAGE }+1 })" "Page { PAGE } (last page)" }

Let me know how it works out :)

Comment: the  Ctrl+F9 was what I was missing!